# Ubuntu 12 Headless Monitor on D2700 Board

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc, webserver

I'm trying to set up a home web server running Ubuntu 12 LTS (Desktop). The server itself boots and runs fine and i'm using a vnc to connect to the server via another desktop.

The issue I have is that if the server is rebooted without a monitor I cannot use the vnc. I believe this is because the OS itself fails to boot. I've found a few answers on Google that suggest making changes to /etc/X11/xorg.conf but this file does not exist on my build and I think its partly because of the D2700 Intel Atom motherboard i'm using. Does anyone have any other suggestions on how I might get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you SSH to the D2700? (In which case it the OS would be booted). Does the board have any serial or firewire lines for a serial console?

Comment: Due to advancements in systems and solution technologies a related [SU Q&A thread](https://superuser.com/q/1445965/) was started in order to keep the proposed solutions matching with the system in question. This will avoid possible confusion by mixing answers for already quite different systems in a single thread.