# How to start X11 on Ubuntu 16.04 without a device providing EDID info on the display connector?

Tags: xorg, ubuntu-16.04, edid

i have an Ubuntu 16.04 installation and it ran fine for me. so i went on and configured it for SSH and GUI remote access. as the machine now no longer needs a ($100+X value and some power consuming) display attached i disconnected all those devices.

when later on remotely logging in to the running machine all went fine. but after rebooting the machine only the SSH access was working whilst remote GUI access failed. checking in more detail unveiled that the x-server failed starting up - probably because it was unable to locate any EDID provider on the display connector.

how can i tell the x server to start up anyways without anything plugged into the display connectors of the computer?

i want to be able to work on the machine remotely using GUI, or out of a sudden replug a capable display and then continue any works on the still open applications. this access to the "main" GUI session should be possible regardless if the computer reboots in its remote place (without any need for plugging or changing physical connections all the time at location).

side note: hardware assisted OpenGL and other GUI features (like xrandr) do a great job for me in both described use cases.

Comment: this question was originally posted on stackoverflow but was found not that well matching in the current form.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56464223/how-to-start-x11-on-ubuntu-16-04-without-a-device-providing-edid-info-on-the-dis

Comment: there was a similar question years ago (2012) on a previous OS and X11 system - but it received no helpful answer. since then the system concepts and solutions have changed quite a bit so that the possible answers might noticeably differ and would lead to confusion if still doing them on the old thread.
https://superuser.com/questions/454598/ubuntu-12-headless-monitor-on-d2700-board

Comment: The EDID is only needed to set a valid mode (resolution and frequency). If you define a mode in Xorg.conf you will most likely not have to supply EDID any longer.

Comment: thanks for your response Eugen - maybe that will be the way to go. lets see if and how i can just use one of the supported modes (like 1024x768) from my existing monitor device and its EDID information. i dont want to enforce this mode but rather have it as a startup fallback option that wont interfere. ...have to find out...